# Angular Js -Unable to call Controller functions

Tags: angularjs

I´m teaching myself a bit Anuglar and  wanted to creating a simple HTML Page.

Created A Simple Controller which I bind to the Body of my HMTL Page:

```
<body data-ng-app="hello" data-ng-controller="controller">
```

In my Testtable i added a href which just log something in Console.

```
<td><a href="" data-ng-click="test()">Test</a></td>
```

My Controller looks Like This:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('controller', function($scope) {
$scope.test = function() {
    console.log('test');
};
});
```

When Clicking on the "link" I see nothing in Console.
What I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

set `data-ng-app="hello"` to set `data-ng-app="myApp"`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="controller">

  <td><a  data-ng-click="test()">Test</a></td>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('controller', function($scope) {
      $scope.test = function() {
        console.log('test');
      };
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for Your Answer. After the Change I get some very cripitc error : Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/  Any Idea?

Comment: I am not seeing anything possible to make error from your current code

Comment: Injector errors are raised when we missed to inject any dependencies

Comment: Is there any dependencie between Angular and Jquery? Or maybe the queue which I load first?

Comment: you don't have to load jquery to run angularjs.If you want to use jquery ,then you can add it,I would prefer to load jquery first.

Comment: please put more code on question,  to understand your issue

Comment: Alright. This is what i actually did...Then I dont see where the code could have problems with dependencies.

Comment: There not much code I can additionaly give here. I added the script  <script type="text/javascript"
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>  and the script where the controller is to my html page.